# function flatten in Clojure

Tags: clojure, scheme, flatten

When translate a function `flatten` from Scheme to Clojure, I have encountered
an error "`Execution error (IllegalArgumentException)"`, Please feel free to comment.

**Clojure** (Encounter error)

```
(defn flatten [x] 
  (cond
    (empty? x) '()
    (not (coll? x)) (list x)
    :else (conj (flatten (first x)) (flatten (rest x)))))

(flatten '((1) 2 ((3 4) 5) ((())) (((6))) 7 8 ()))
```

**Scheme**

```
> (define (flatten x)
    (cond ((null? x) '())
          ((not (pair? x)) (list x))
          (else (append (flatten (car x))
                        (flatten (cdr x))))))
 
> (flatten '((1) 2 ((3 4) 5) ((())) (((6))) 7 8 ()))
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an implementation that works for me

```
(defn flatten [x]
  (cond
    (not (coll? x)) (list x)
    (empty? x) '()
    :else (concat (flatten (first x)) (flatten (rest x)))))

(comment
  (flatten '((1) 2 ((3 4) 5) ((())) (((6))) 7 8 ())))

  ;returns (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
```

The only difference is that I put first the `(not (coll? x))` and then the `empty?` (because (empty? 3) will throw an error)

The other change is the `concat` instead of `conj`. I don't think it's recommended to use concat because it can throw a Stack Overflow Error (see : https://stuartsierra.com/2015/04/26/clojure-donts-concat) but it works in this case ...

Comment: Also you also might want to remplace `coll?` by `sequential?` ...

Comment: You also might want to have a look at the internal implementation of flatten in clojure.core : https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.10.1/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L7136

Comment: Finally if I look at the implementation in scheme, I seed the test is `null?` and you replaced it by `empty?` , you might want to replace it by `nil?` instead ...

Answer (score 2):

One more version, based on Alan Thompson's solution:

```
(defn flat [data]
  (reduce (fn [result e]
            (if (not (sequential? e))
              (conj result e)
              (into result (flat e))))
          [] data))
```

Tests:

```
(clojure.test/are [result arg]
  (= result (flat arg))
  [1 2 3] [1 2 3]
  [1 2 3] [1 [2 3]]
  [1 2 3] [1 [2 [3]]]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7] [[0] [1 2 3] [4 5 [6 7]]])
=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate version that may be a bit more straightforward:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn flatten
  [data]
  (loop [result []
         items  data]
    (if (empty? items)
      result
      (let [item       (first items)
            items-next (rest items)]
        (if (not (sequential? item))
          (recur
            (conj result item)
            items-next)
          (recur
            (into result (flatten item))
            items-next))))))

(dotest
  (is= (flatten [1 2 3]) [1 2 3])
  (is= (flatten [1 [2 3]]) [1 2 3])
  (is= (flatten [1 [2 [3]]]) [1 2 3])
  (is= (flatten [[0] [1 2 3] [4 5 [6 7]]]) [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7])

  ; Cannot flatten a scalar value - we don't want (flatten 3) => [3]
  (throws? (flatten 3)))
```

Note that we avoid tricks like wrapping every scalar value in a list, so we don't get the non-intuitive result `(flatten 3) => [3]`.

---

Build using [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).